# Get object's index from an array

Tags: javascript, jquery

My array looks something like this:

```
var someArray = 

    [
        { id: 'someID', name: 'someName', title: 'someTitle' },
        { id: 'anotherID', name: 'anotherName', title: 'anotherTitle' },
        { id: 'otherID', name: 'otherName', title: 'otherTitle' }
    ];
```

I want to get index reference of an object that who's `id === 'anotherID'` in reference with `someArray`

I know that I can use `$.grep()` to return an object:

```
var resultArray = $.grep(columns, function(e){return e.id === 'anotherID'});
```

`resultArray` will return an array of objects that match the condition of anonymous function, but it will not return an index of that object in `someArray`

I am looking for JavaScript/Jquery solution. 
Thank you.

Comment: are you using underscore.js? They have algo for this and many more

Comment: @user814628 Question is tagged with `jquery`. Pay attention.

Comment: @FelixKling It may and at same time, may not. Since he is using `jquery`, then it's not duplicated.

Comment: @RaphaelDDL: Then you might want to close it as duplicate of this one: [jQuery: Index of element in array where predicate](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3241881/218196).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using jQuery's `$.each`:

```
var posIndex = '';
$.each(someArray, function(i){
    if(someArray[i].id === 'anotherID'){
        posIndex = i;
        return false; /*Stop iterating once found. Tip from Felix Kling*/
    }
});
```

See [example fiddle (upper code part)](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/eJycX/).

As you see, using jQuery is alot easier than normal JS `for`.

<del>This answer considers that each `id` is really an *identifier* (a.k.a. **unique**) or else `posIndex` will return the position of the last object which has `anotherID`.</del>

**Update**
Added 'Felix Kling' tip of `return false;`. Now it will return the first match only. If have more than one id with same value, use below. Thanks Felix.

---

If you think that might have multiple equal ids, I suggest that `posIndex` becomes an array and then you read the array later. Example:

```
var posIndexArray = [];
$.each(someOtherArray, function (i) {
    if (someOtherArray[i].id === 'anotherID') {
        posIndexArray.push(i);
    }
});
```

And `posIndexArray` will be a comma separated list of indexes you can then use `$.each` on it to do whatever you want with the indexes.

See [example fiddle (lower code part)](http://jsfiddle.net/RaphaelDDL/eJycX/).

Comment: The better answer so far, since the Q is tagged `jquery` AND it comes with a fiddle.

Comment: @Jeffman Thanks. I've updated answer to cover when there's more than one id with same value (non-unique `id`).

Comment: @RaphaelDDL Great answer! I am giving you +1 for a really nice and efficient answer. I would also give you +2 for fiddle and the second part of the answer, but I can't. Thank you

Comment: If you assume that the ID's are unique, you can `return false;` from the callback to avoid iterating over the remaining elements once you found a match.

Comment: @FelixKling Added your tip to the answer. That's a good one btw. Thanks +1 :)

Answer (score 1):

A simple `for`:

```
var elementIndex = false;
for ( var index = 0, length = someArray.length; index < length; index++ ) {
    if ( someArray[index].id === 'anotherID' ) {
        elementIndex = index;
        break;
    }
}

if ( elementIndex !== false ) {
    console.log(elementIndex);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is going to be to write your own function (unless you have access to the built-in `indexOf` method and it works for you:

```
var indexOf = function(array, predicate) {
   for(var i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
       if(predicate(array[i])) {
           return i;
       }
   } 
   return -1;
}
```

Which you could then call like:

```
var index = indexOf(someArray, function(e){ return e.id === 'anotherID'; });
```

Answer (score 1):

.reduce() is not supported by IE8

One liner using reduce:

```
someArray.reduce(function(p,c,i){return c.id=='anotherID'?i:p},-1);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this pretty easily using either plain ol' JavaScript or jQuery if you so choose!

*le vanilla*

```js
function getById(id, objects) {
  for (var i = 0, length = objects.length; i < length; i++) {
    if (objects[i].id === id) {
      return i;
    }
  }

  return -1;
}
```

jQueryyy

```js
function getById(id, objects) {
  var index = -1;

  $.each(objects, function(i) {
    if (this.id === id) {
      index = i;
      return false;
    }
  });

  return index;
}
```

From that point, you could just call your little handy-dandy helper function and check that you got a good index.

```
var index = getById('otherId', someArray);

if (~index) {
  doSomethingAwesome(someArray[index]);
}
```